# Android Onclick priority: ListView or ImageView in ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, onclicklistener

Theorical question

I have a `listview` populated with items, which layout is defined by one `TextView` and one `ImageView`.
I set an `onclick listener` on my `listview` for any item.
I set an `onclick listener` on my `ImageView` within my layout

Which one gets the priority when I click on my image and why?

How do I write code to manage this priorization?

Thanks!

Comment: When you click on imageview then it will call your imageview click listner and when you click on other portion of imageview in your listitem cell then it will call listitem click listner. And for that you need to set android:focusable="true" to your imageview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the attributes

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

for a layout that contains `TextView` and one `ImageView`.